# Trying to Create Countdown Timer for an array of Times

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build myself a little workout tool. In Python I am building a random array of times, each linked to a random array of exercises. On the front end (in my html template) I am listing all of these in a class menu on the side. I then use my javascript to grab the entire array of exercises and times with document.getElementsByClassName("exercises") or document.getElementsByClassName("times").

I have a start button which once clicked will start my workout. I want it to: for each element in document.getElementsByClassName: run a countdown timer until time has expired, displaying the countdown timer and exercise on the main screen.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var times = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
  // console.log(times.item(0).innerHTML);
  var exercises = document.getElementsByClassName('exercise');
  var display = document.getElementById('currentexercise');
  for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {

      var current = parseInt(times.item(i).innerHTML);
      var timeinterval = current;
      for (var j = 1; j <= timeinterval; j++) {
        
        runclock(current, i, exercises.item(i).innerHTML, display);
        current = current - 1;


      }


  }

 

  function runclock(current, i, exercise, display) {


    var x = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(current);
      var now = new Date();
      var endoftime = new Date();
      endoftime.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + parseInt(current));
      var distance = endoftime - now;
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      console.log('hit');
      document.getElementById('mytimer').innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
      display.innerHTML = exercise;
      
    }, 1000);

  }
}
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-3">
    {% if workout %}
      <ul class="list-group">
        {% for exercise in workout %}
          <li class="list-group-item exercises">{{ exercise.0 }}, {{ exercise.1 }}</li>
          <li class = "hidden time">{{ exercise.1 }}</li>
          <li class = "hidden exercise">{{ exercise.0 }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class = "col-sm-9">
    {% if form %}
      <h1> Spences Workout Form</h1>
      <form action="/" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    {% else %}
      <h1>Spences Workout Tool</h1>
      <h3>Rounds: {{ rounds }}</h3>
      <button id = "startbutton" onclick = "myfunction()">Start</button>
    {% endif %}

    <div id = "mytimer"></div>
    <div id = "currentexercise"></div>



  </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

This is very very quickly going through each command, but I want it to work just like a regular clock timer. I'm having a hard time understanding how to use setTimeout/setInterval properly. Please let me know how to basically run each "j" in my second forloop only once per second.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python.  What does `{{ exercise.1 }}` do?  Should it not be like `{{ exercise.time }}`?  I imagine that `exercise.0` is the name of the exercise and `exercise.1` is the time of the exercise.  What is the format for the time?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin is right. This is Django/Jinja syntax and is backend related stuff. Please, post a real live example (what a browser sees), so we can debug it easier.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is a function that calls another function asynchronously after a period of time. You need to program taking care of it. For example, if you want to do a typical `sleep(1000)` operation, you should know that you need to tell what function to execute after one second.

```
function myfunction(current=1) {
  var times = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
  // console.log(times.item(0).innerHTML);
  var exercises = document.getElementsByClassName('exercise');
  var display = document.getElementById('currentexercise');
  for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {

      var end = parseInt(times.item(i).innerHTML);
      if(current <= end) {
        runclock(current, i, exercises.item(i).innerHTML, display);
      }
  }

  setTimeout(function() { myfunction(current+1) }, 1000);

  function runclock(current, i, exercise, display) {
      console.log(current);
      var now = new Date();
      var endoftime = new Date();
      endoftime.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + parseInt(current));
      var distance = endoftime - now;
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      console.log('hit');
      document.getElementById('mytimer').innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
      display.innerHTML = exercise;
  }
}
```

There are some optimizations and design patterns you can enhance here, but the problem with timers should be fixed with this (or something similar, as I can't know how is the complete HTML page without a working example).

Comment: This method won't show the proper time remaining.  You can't rely on setTimout calling the function at exactly the expected delay.  Also, in this version runclock will only be called once.

Comment: "You can't rely on setTimeout calling the function at exactly the expected delay" Why not? If I want it to execute in 1000ms, what should I expect?

Comment: `Also, in this version runclock will only be called once`: It's called once for every item each time `myfunction` is called, exactly `times.item(i).innerHTML` times per item.

Comment: Because javascript is sigle threaded (with the exception of web worker)  that means if any other javascript code that takes time will postpone the callback at a later time.

Comment: Then you can't change the DOM.

Comment: `Then you can't change the DOM`: Why not? Probably this could be one of the "other" wrong decisions made here. But @SPatrick still does not knows the basics of `setTimeout` and the question asks for it. Let's help understand it, before rewriting the entire code, or discussing which programming pattern will you or me use in a work environment with that problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183094/discussion-between-dominique-fortin-and-emi).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest :

```js
function attr(o, attrName) {
  var stop, value;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(o.attributes, function(e){
    if (stop) return;
    if (e.nodeName === attrName) {
      value = e.nodeValue;
      stop = 1;
    }
  });
  return value;
}

function init() {
  var exercises = document.getElementsByClassName('exercises');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(exercises, function(e){
    var dataJSON = attr(e,'data');
    var data = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
    e.innerHTML = data.name+", "+Math.floor(data.time/1000);
  });
  exercises[0].onclick();
}
init();

function seeExerciseTime (o) {
  var currentexercise = document.getElementsByClassName('currentexercise');
  if (currentexercise.length && currentexercise.length > 0) {
    currentexercise[0].classList.remove('currentexercise');
  }
  var dataJSON = attr(o,'data');
  var data = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
  o.classList.add('currentexercise');
  document.getElementById('currentexercise').innerHTML = data.name;
}

var startoftime = 0;
function myfunction() {
  startoftime = (new Date()).getTime();

  setTimeout(tick, 1000);
}

function tick() {
  var currentexercise = document.getElementsByClassName('currentexercise');
  if (currentexercise.length && currentexercise.length > 0) {
    var dataJSON = attr(currentexercise[0],'data');
    var data = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    var distance = data.time - (now - startoftime);
    if (distance < 0) distance = 0;
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById('mytimer').innerHTML = minutes +"m "+ seconds +"s ";
  }

  setTimeout(tick, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-3">
  Click on exercise to see the time remaining for the exercise.
      <ul class="list-group">
        <!-- {% for exercise in workout %} -->
          <li class="list-group-item exercises" data="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Alpha&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:60000}" onclick="seeExerciseTime(this)"></li>
          <li class="list-group-item exercises" data="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Beta&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:605345}" onclick="seeExerciseTime(this)"></li>
          <li class="list-group-item exercises" data="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Gamma&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:902323}" onclick="seeExerciseTime(this)"></li>
        <!-- {% endfor %} -->
      </ul>
  </div>
    <div id = "mytimer"></div>
    <div id = "currentexercise"></div>

  <div class = "col-sm-9">
    <!-- {% if form %}
      <h1> Spences Workout Form</h1>
      <form action="/" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    {% else %} -->
      <h3>Spences Workout Tool</h1>
      <h4>Rounds: <!-- {{ rounds }} -->3</h3>
      <button id = "startbutton" onclick = "myfunction()">Start</button>
    <!-- {% endif %} -->

  </div>
</div>
```

I've moved stuff around so that we can see the time better.